# Rails Mailer Is not authentication with Postfix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, squirrelmail, postfix-mta

My Email configuration is following

```
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

     config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

     config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "172.5.8.2",
      port: 25,
      domain: "abc.ph",
      user_name: "username",
      password: "password",
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true
     }

 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://172.2.3.4' }
```

I am new one with postfix mail. My postfix mail setting is following

```
[root@sushi-mc3 ~]# postconf -n

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = mydomain
mynetworks = 172.5.8.2/16, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

But it gives us error

```
 FATAL #012EOFError (end of file reached):#012
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't squirrelmail just a webmail client for _reading_ email? It should have nothing to do with _sending_ mail from Rails. It's probably your postfix configuration that is causing trouble.

Comment: @zwippie could you please tell me what configuration I have missed

Comment: @zwippie i am also changing the subject line